# F# error: Wrong type expected?

Tags: types, casting, f#

```
let distance (x:(float * float)): float =
    sqrt ((fst x * fst x) + (snd x * snd x))

let getClosestPair (pairs:(float * float) list) =
    let mutable closest = (0.0, 0.0)
    if List.isEmpty pairs then
        (infinity, infinity)
    else
        closest <- pairs.[0]
        for i in pairs do
            if (distance i) < (distance closest) then closest <- i
```

The above function goes through a list of float pairs. Each pair acts like a coordinate on the cartesian plane. The function finds the closest pair to the origin. The for loop at the bottom generates a type error.

> "This expression was expected to have type float * float but here has
>   type unit"

How would I fix this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `if` block you are returning a `float * float` tuple, but in the `else` block you are mutating the `closest` variable and returning `unit`. These two blocks must return the same type.

Change your `else` block to this:

```
else
    closest <- pairs.[0]
    for i in pairs do
        if (distance i) < (distance closest) then closest <- i
    closest
```

That ensures you are returning the final result of the `closest` variable in the `else` block, which will in turn ensure you are returning a `float * float` tuple in both the `if` and `else` paths.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. A second set of eyes never hurts.